# How can I have two types of parameters in one URL, where one starts with "#" and the other one starts with "&" and without replacing the other?

Tags: javascript, jquery

2 types of parameters: sizes and prices. Currently, I can click to select/highlight only one in sizes column and also only one for prices column wiithout affecting one from the other.

When i click a size, a URL parameter "#size=4" is added.
clicking another size will replace current URL parameter to `"#size=5"` or `"#size=6".`

When i click a price, a parameter `"#pmin=30&pmax=40"` is added.
Clicking another price will replace current parameter with `"#pmin=40&pmax=50"` or

```
"#pmin=50&pmax=60".
```

Problem is it also replaces the size parameter.

Question:

How can I have these two types of parameters combined together in one URL, where one starts with "#" and the other one starts with "&" and without replacing the other?

Target URL parameter:

```
example.com/#size=5&pmin=40&pmax=50 
or 
example.com/#pmin=40&pmax=50&size=5
```

I have the codes in this => http://jsfiddle.net/philcyb/af70tw19/2/ however, the URL and parameter is not showing.  It has to be recreated locally or in anyway so that parameters are showing.

HTML:

```
<div class="divContainer">
    <div>Sizes</div>
    <a class="sizes" href="#size=4" border="0">
        <div class="inDivSize">4</div>
    </a>
    <a class="sizes" href="#size=5" border="0">
        <div class="inDivSize">5</div>
    </a>
    <a class="sizes" href="#size=6" border="0">
        <div class="inDivSize">6</div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="divContainer">
    <div>Prices</div>
    <a class="prices" href="#pmin=30&pmax=40" border="0">
        <div class="inDivPrice"> $30 - $40 </div>
    </a>
    <a class="prices" href="#pmin=40&pmax=50" border="0">
        <div class="inDivPrice"> $40 - $50 </div>
    </a>
    <a class="prices" href="#pmin=50&pmax=60" border="0">
        <div class="inDivPrice"> $50 - $60 </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.divContainer {
    float: left; 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 80px; 
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    text-align: center;
}
.inDivSize:hover, .inDivPrice:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.inDivSizeClicked, .inDivPriceClicked {
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
```

JS/JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $(".inDivSize").click(function() {
            $(".inDivSize").removeClass("inDivSizeClicked");
            $(this).addClass("inDivSizeClicked");
        });
        $(".inDivPrice").click(function() {
            $(".inDivPrice").removeClass("inDivPriceClicked");
            $(this).addClass("inDivPriceClicked");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to hook the click event of the size element

```
$(".sizes").click(function(e) {
        var psize = $(this).attr('psize');
        $('.prices').each(function() {
            var priceParam = $(this).attr('href');
            $(this).attr('href', priceParam.indexOf('size=') === -1 ? (priceParam + '&size=' + psize) : priceParam.replace(/size=\d/,  'size='+ psize));
        });
    });

$('.prices').click(function() {
        var priceParam = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log(priceParam);
            $('.sizes').each(function() {
                var psize = $(this).attr('psize');
                $(this).attr('href', priceParam.indexOf('size=') === -1 ? (priceParam + '&size=' + psize) : priceParam.replace(/size=\d/, 'size=' + psize));
            });
    });
```

add this code in document ready
and i also modified the divContainer i added a psize attribute this way i can still determine what size is the a element corresponds to.

```
<div class="divContainer">
    <div>Sizes</div>
    <a class="sizes" href="#size=4" psize="4" border="0">
        <div class="inDivSize">4</div>
    </a>
    <a class="sizes" href="#size=5" psize="5" border="0">
        <div class="inDivSize">5</div>
    </a>
    <a class="sizes" href="#size=6" psize="6" border="0">
        <div class="inDivSize">6</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

hope this help.

Comment: Hi daotan. This is the right implementation that I needed.  However, just one more small thing that maybe you can still resolve.
two types of parameters are combined alright. But when I click a new size, the price parameter is reset or gone again.  Can the price parameter remain visible? even if I click a new size?

Comment: Hi Philcyb. I modified my answer hope this will help. also i create fiddle for you to check. http://jsfiddle.net/af70tw19/4/

Comment: thank you so much! It's perfectly working as I needed.  Especially the fiddle. I will consider this an answer.

Comment: Once again thank you for your solution.  I'm trying to reverse the position of the URL parameters, that is, to use sizes first before prices. Something like this: 
    #size=6&pmin=50&pmax=60

Comment: please see my update in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/af70tw19/5/
what i did is i add a property in prices element a pmax and pmin in this way we are not limited in what we can do to the data. :)

Comment: Thanks. it works like a charm. Except in IE8, it only shows 1 parameter.  But thank you again. :)